# How to use png++ (C++ library) on Windows?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw

I am trying to use this C++ library ([png++](https://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.9/)) on Windows, but I unable to compile any program when I use it. Example of Code I am using to test:

```
#include <png++/png.hpp>
#include <png.h>

int main(){
//anything
}
```

When I try to compile using `g++ -I path/png++ main.cpp -o main`, I get

```
fatal error: png++/png.hpp: No such file or directory
 
#include <png++/png.hpp>
```

I understand png++ depends on [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), I tried adding it as an I- flag, i.e. compile using
`g++ -I path/png++ -I path/libpng main.cpp -o main`, but it doesn't resolve the issue, png.h is found by the compiler but not png++/png.hpp.

I hope someone will be able to help.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to install this file such that one of your include folders has a png++ folder containing the header.

Comment: `g++ -I path/png++` probably should be `g++ -I path` because I don't think you have a path/png++/png++ folder.

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say. @drescherjm

Comment: What I am trying to say is you need to examine and solve the path problem on your PC. Typing: `#include <png++/png.hpp>` means that you are telling the compiler that 1 of the folders that are in your compilers include search path has a `png++` subfolder containing `png.hpp`

Comment: Thanks, it worked (I found another error, but it's not an include problem)